# Mongoose return a empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose return a empty array when i am trying to use `find()` function.Can any one help me with this please?

**users.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String    
});
const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users');    
module.exports = user;
```

**test_helper.js**

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user_test');

    before((done)=>{
        mongoose.connection.once('open',()=>{
            console.log('Connected');
        }).on('error', ()=>{
            console.log('Error');
        });
        done();
    });

    beforeEach((done)=>{
        mongoose.connection
                .collections
                .users
                .drop(()=>{
            done();
        });
     });
```

**create_user.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');


describe('Create a user',()=>{
    it('it should create a new user',(done)=>{
        let joe = new User({
            name : "Joe"
        });
        joe.save().then(()=>{
            assert(!joe.isNew);
            done();
        });
    });
})
```

**reading-users.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');


describe('This will read all users', () => {
    before((done) => {
        joe = new User({name:'joe'});
        joe.save().then(() => done());
    });
    it('It Should find all users named joe', (done) => {
        User.findOne({name:"Joe"})
            .then((foo)=>{
                //assert(users[0]._id.toString()===joe._id.toString());
                console.log(foo);
                console.log(joe);
                done();
        });
    });
});
```

=============================log==========================================

> (node:3324) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect. 
>   Create a user Connected
>       √ it should create a new user (274ms)
>
> This will read all users 
>     [] { _id: 5bfa98eb6bd05d0cfc5d639d, name:
>     'joe', __v: 0 }
>       √ It Should find all users named joe
>
> 2 passing (1s)

Comment: Nothing here should be returning an "array". I presume you have probably changed the code several times from `find()` to `findOne()`? Being the former returns an array but the other does not. Add `mongoose.set('debug', true)` **at the top** of your tests in order to see the output of what is actually being sent to MongoDB. And most importantly "when"!

Comment: a typo: 'joe' and 'Joe' are different

Comment: @piisexactly3 The "difference" is in the description of the test, not in the data or query. So that's not it.

Comment: @Neil Lunn...I tried but had zero result

Comment: @piisexactly3 corrected it but still same...I have worked in this since two days..can anyone help me please

Comment: "I tried" does not really tell us anything. Please do what you were asked, then edit the code in the question to show us you actually did that and include the output you see as a result of doing that.

Comment: content updated

Comment: Well stupid question, are you sure that record was created ? do you see "Joe" in your MongoDB Ui tool ?

Comment: @Neil Lunn I'm referring to the 'joe' that was saved in the "before" block, not the description

Comment: @Steave Jones Did you correct the 'joe' in the before block?

Comment: Yes @piisexactly3, already changed that too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause for this problem is that every time you start your test, created records will always removed before your test get started. This is occurring inside the `beforeEach` block in your `test_helper.js` file. try to replace`beforeEach` with `afterEach`.

```
afterEach((done)=>{
    mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(()=>{
        done();
    });
});
```